# How to clear the background of one ImageView while moving smoothly to the next activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

In Android, I have Activity M, M call the intent of Activity N.
So that means:
M ==> N

M has an ImageView, with a background of a picture.
I find that even I move to Activity N, the memory for that background picture of the ImageView in Activity M is still occupied.
If my application is big, this will cause a little problem in reducing available memory.

So in Activity M, when before I start the intent of Activity N, I set the ImageView background as null.
It will clear the background image, but:
since it takes a little time from M to N,
so I can see a blank ImageView in M, before I see the inteface of N.

I do not like this.
But if I have moved to N, there is no way for me to find the ID of the ImageView of M to set it as null.

How to deal with this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: This seems totally normal. Your Activity is just paused (and/or stopped), but still exists on the stack. Is this causing an actual issue?

Comment: where do you set the imageview to null?

Comment: @ kcoppock, It reduces the available memory. Especially if my application has many activities, and each activity has many ImageViews with pictures as background.

Comment: @Raghunandan, before start the intent of the next Activity N. I also tried to use it in the onPause. Same results: I can see a blank ImageView in M, before I see the inteface of N.

Comment: @user1914692 i don't know but this should not happen i guess. coz when your activity is paused its in background.

Comment: @user1914692 instead of making it null try unbinding the drawable background image.

Comment: @Raghunandan "when your activity is paused its in background". Yes, it is in background, so it still takes memory, I think.

Comment: when it's in background its paused. you can unbind the drawable in onPause.